# When we use 's ' with a verb and what is subject and verb match?

Tags: verbs, pronouns, nouns

hello guys i want to know that when we use 's' with a verb and when not and what is subject and verb match condition is the subject is singular then we use singular verb and if the verb is plural then we use plural verb is this statement is true

then why we use he goes when he is an singular subject.

Answer (score 1):

Don't fall into the trap of thinking that every word which ends in 'S' is a plural - it isn't! That is just for nouns, and even then there are a few exceptions.

The different forms of the verb "to go" are like any other verb forms.

> He goes to school.

This means he goes to school *every day*. If you wanted to talk about just *one* occasion, you might say:

> He *went* to school today.

or

> He *is going* to school today.

Comment: I go, you go, he goes, we go, they go. As Astralbee says, _goes_ isn't a plural, it's just the way the verb works.